# Rationale for difference in "default" access-specifier for a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, access-specifier

I know that there're few differences between `struct` and `class` in C++. I also understand the reason(s) for few of the difference(s). Like this one,

- Members of struct are *public by
  default*; members of class are
  *private by default*. The reason why members of struct are *public by default*, is to make `C++-struct` compatible with `C-struct`.  And the reason why member of class are *private by default*, is to introduce the concept of *data encapsulation* (i.e enforcing object-oriented principles/techniques/etc).

What I don't understand is this, quoting the Standard $11.2/2 [class.access.base]

> In absence of an access-specifier for
>   a base class, public is assumed when
>   the derived class is declared struct
>   and private is assumed when the class
>   is declared class.

What is the rationale for this twist and anti-uniformity? **Why is this difference needed?**

Example from the Standard,

```
class B {  };
class D1 : private B {  };
class D2 : public B { };
class D3 : B { };         //B private by default
struct D4 : public B { };
struct D5 : private B { };
struct D6 : B { };        //B public by default
class D7 : protected B { };
struct D8 : protected B { };
```

> Here B is a public base of D2, D4, and
>   D6, a private base of D1, D3, and D5,
>   and a protected base of D7 and D8.

---

## EDIT

Some of you might say, this difference makes sense given the default access for struct and class being different (the difference given in the bullet-point above). But I think, `inherited-struct` altogether is incompatible with `C-struct` (which doesn't support inheritance), no matter how you derive it. I may be wrong though. That is why I'm seeking good explanations, possibly with examples! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think it's a twist, you have consistency with member sub-objects and base class sub-objects. They are both public for classes declared with `struct` and private for classes declared with `class`. Simple and easy to remember.

Comment: @Charles : the point is not that it's  "Simple and easy to remember", as you said. I'm seeking an explanation for this difference, not what you said.

Comment: @Nawaz: What difference? If `class` inheritance had been `public` by default and member access `private` then you would have a difference that required justification. As the rule is the simpler choice, there doesn't really need to be any further justification.

Comment: +1, liking this reasoning :) Also note that it will give consistency wrt the injected class name. If the inheritance wouldn't be public, then given `struct A : SomeStruct { };` doing `A::SomeStruct` would be inaccessible outside the class.

Comment: @Nawaz: the point is that the base class can be seen as a special implicit member of the class.  So both being public by default means that a struct is always an open data class.

Comment: @stefaanv and @Charles : I think, I understood now. stefaanv's comment's made me to think from different angle. Now it seems obvious to me :D. Accepted.

Comment: In fact, now I think, how can I ask such stupid questions. tsk tsk. :-s

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't this make sense given the default access for struct and class being different? (as in your first bullet point)

If you inherit from a struct (which by default is public) then without specifying an access modifier, you are implying public inheritenance whereas If you inherit from a class (which by default is private) then without specifying an access modifier, you are implying private inheritenance.

Did I miss something in your question?