# Why does C++ have both classes and structs?

Tags: c++, class, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences between struct and class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c)

If the only difference between structs and classes is the default access specifier(in C++), then why does C++ also have classes?

Comment: see [struct vs. class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543515/structs-vs-classes-in-c seems like it might be relevant, among others.

Comment: @greg I'm not asking what the differences are...

Comment: Without any backing facts and just by extrapolating, it probably was because initially, `class` and `struct` were distinct (probably that classes only had methods). If it's the case, then when they added methods to `struct`s, they would have had to support both classes and struct to remain backwards-compatible with both C and older C++.

Comment: See also [In C++, why struct is in fact class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427759/in-c-why-struct-is-in-fact-class) or [C/C++ Struct vs Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750270/c-c-struct-vs-class).

Comment: @JohnMcG someone is obviously mad.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, it's backward compatibility with C.
Second (and more importantly), it helps describe your intent.  The standard convention is that PODs should be denoted with `struct` and collections of data and behavior should be denoted with `class`.

Comment: Well then why are class-style actions allowed in structs, like operator overloading? Doesn't that break compatibility?

Comment: In this case, it's about *convention*.  C++, in this and many other ways, lets you do lots of things, whether they are good ideas or not.

Comment: @MisterSir - no, **backwards** compatibility means that C code using structs would compile and work as expected under C++. Your example (struct with behavior) is a C++ code, and naturally it would not work under C as C++ does not guarantee **forward** compatibility

Comment: Yes. It means that the _compiler_ is backward compatible in that it can (to some degree) compile old C code. It does not mean that your shiny new C++ code will work in a C compiler.

Comment: @davka: Strictly speaking, the reason it does not work under C is that C does not guarantee forward compatibility ;)

Comment: @Tomalak: I think one of C's biggest failings is that it wasn't created forward-compatible with C++0x. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want classes to have the default access specifier to be private when designing object-oriented hierarchies, but structs need to have the default access specifier to be public to preserve compatiblity with C.

Answer (score 0):

Backwards compatibility with C.  C didn't have classes, but it had structs.

Note that this is "backwards compatibility" in the text of the .c file only.  In C++ structs are really classes, with a default exposure of `public` instead of a default exposure of `private`.

```
class Bob {
   // I haven't overridden the exposure, so it's private
   int age;
   int height;

   public:
     Bob();

};


struct Bob {
   // I haven't overridden the exposure, so it's public
   int age;
   int height;

   // note the constructor defaults to the "default" constructor.
};
```

A true C style struct is defined as so

```
extern "C" {
  struct Bob {
     int age;
     int height;
  };
}
```

In which case age becomes more of an alias of "offset +0" and height becomes more of an alias of "offset +(sizeof(int) + alignment to memory manager boundary) instead of being conceptual fields which can be implemented in any desired manner.

Comment: -1 Nonsense; `extern "C"` is used to specify linkage. It is *not* a "drop into the C language" switch. e.g. `extern "C" { struct T { T() {} }; }` is perfectly valid. (The rest of your answer is correct.)

Comment: Where's the part in my post that declares "drop into the C language"?  I merely stated that a "true C style struct is defined this way..."

Comment: Yes, which is not true. You're still declaring+defining a C++ struct. (Though I see now that perhaps you merely meant to talk about C-compatibility?)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has posted, the main difference is default protection level (i.e. public or private). However, it's also a good indication on the actual use of the data structure. For example, sometimes you might want a light-weight structure, similar to a java bean. In that case you might just have:

```
struct point {
   float x, y;
};
```

It's clear that you're not using any C++ features here, versus:

```
class point {
public:
   float x, y;
};
```

It's less clear what your intention is. I'd likely note the second example as bad code because someone didn't provide getters and setters.